# Codeql Scanning Alerts "Dereferenced variable may be null"

Tags: java, lombok, codeql

In my code I get the above warning. Here is the part of the code where I get it,

```
@Data
@Builder
public class Employee {
  private String email;
  @Data
  @Builder
  public static class Department{
    @Singular(value = "department")
    private final Set<String> set;
  }
}
```

Variable set  may be null at this access as suggested by  null guard.

need to resolve 'set' is not added null value which is not give Code Scanning Alerts "Dereferenced variable may be null"

Comment: Where exactly is this alert shown? It should be shown at a usage of `set`, but you did not include this in your question. Additionally, the text "as suggested by _this_ null guard" should have a link at "_this_" which explains why CodeQL thinks the variable can be `null`. Can you please include this location in your question? Or if this is an alert on a public pull request on GitHub, it would be easiest if you just linked to the alert.

Answer (score -1):

You used **final**.

```
private final Set<String> set;
```

The final is used that >>**value**<< or >>**ref to the object**<< cannot be changed.

To fix your problem init in >>**all constructors**<< or >>**spot**<< or delete final.

**Option 1**

```
import java.util.*; //there are 8 different Sets to chose from
private final Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
```

**Option 2**

```
import java.util.*;
public Department(){ set = new HashSet<>(); }
```

**Option 3** ... you still need to call init (set = new HashSet<>())

```
import java.util.*;
private Set<String> set;
```

This link might helps you find more about **final**: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_(Java)